# Dropdown list in the toolbar displaying as textbox in kendo MVC

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

we use to have telerik grids before, I am trying to upgrade to kendo grids, I could able to display kendo grid, I am getting issues with the dropdown list.

I got a kendo sync error resolved by using deferred true.

HTML code

```
@(Html.Kendo().DropDownList().Name("businessUnitId")
            .DataTextField("Text")
            .DataValueField("Value")
            .HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "k-dropdown-custom"})
            .BindTo(Model.AvailableBusinessUnits)
            .Deferred(true))

jquery code
 $('#ddlbusinessUnitId').on("change", function () {
            @*var buzUnit = $('#@Html.FieldIdFor(model => model.BusinessUnitId )').val();
            var buzUnitName = $("#BuzUnitId option:selected").text();*@
                var bUnit = $('#ddlbusinessUnitId').val();
            @*if (buzUnit == null || buzUnit == '') {
                $("#spanErrorMessage").text("Please select Business Unit.");
                     }*@
                $.ajax({
                    type: "Get",
                    url: "/RiskAnalytics/GetVaRDaysDisplay",
                    data: { businessUnit: bUnit },
                    success: function () {
                        //$("commodityVaRGrid").html("");
                        //$("commodityVaRGrid").html(data);
                    },
                    error: function (err) {
                        alert('err');
```

controller code

```
public ActionResult GetVaRDaysDisplay(int businessUnit)``
        {
            return PartialView("_PartialVarDays", new VaRDaysModel());
```

Comment: not rendering a dropdownlist properly is related to some javascript errors. can you check the console log if there some error. another possible situation is regarding the duplicate Ids. you have to ensure that the id **businessUnitId** is not repeated in another part of the page ie. another partial view

Comment: Are you trying to have a dropdown inside the grid or have the grid update based on a dropdown?